# Can the boundaries of two pentagons intersect at $20$ points?

Tags: combinatorics, curves, intersection-theory

This question is a follow-up to [Maximum number of intersections between a quadrilateral and a pentagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708006/maximum-number-of-intersections-between-a-quadrilateral-and-a-pentagon/2708018#2708018), where it is shown that the boundaries $\partial Q,\partial P$ of a quadrilateral and a pentagon in the plane cannot intersect at more than $16$ points, since each side of $\partial Q$  meets $\partial P$ at an even number of points.

> **Q:** Given the boundaries $\partial P_1, \partial P_2$ of two pentagons in
>    the plane, is it possible that $$ \left|\partial P_1 \cap \partial P_2
>  \right| = 20?$$

Each side of $\partial P_1$ meets $\partial P_2$ at an even number of points, so equality is attained iff there is some configuration such that each side of $\partial P_1$ meets each side of $\partial P_2$ except one. $\left|\partial P_1 \cap \partial P_2\right| = 18$ is possible, as shown below,
[image]

and I believe that $\left|\partial P_1 \cap \partial P_2\right| = 20$ is *im*possible, but I am failing to prove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Theorem 4 from Černy et al.'s "[On the number of intersections of two polygons](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0720/2248170e7b8a9e03ebf240c04f79550a1b62.pdf)" (2003), the number of intersections is bounded by $$5\times 5-\left\lceil \frac56 \right\rceil-5=19$$
Therefore $18$ is the maximum.

Alternatively, Theorem 5 gives the exact value $4\times 5-2=18$.

These maximal intersection numbers are hard to compute when both polygons have an odd number of vertices. Otherwise there are general formulas given by Theorem 1 and 2.

Edit: found a better result in Günther's "[The maximum number of intersections of two polygons](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.746.9138&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" (2012).

> **Theorem:** the maximal number of intersections between an $n$-polygon and an $m$-polygon with $n$ and $m$ both odd is $(n-1)(m-1)+2$.

Comment: (+1) Nice, essentially it is enough to study a few configurations, according to the number of vertices of the convex envelopes of $P_1$ and $P_2$. But I would be happier in having a proof independent from a case-by-case analysis.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I added a stronger result. I don't have time to have a look at the proof, but since it is general I guess that they found something more clever than a case by case analysis.

Comment: Gunther's approach is more general and cleaner, indeed. Thanks for your contribution. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're very welcome.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the edit.