# proof that the maximum number of intersections of a triangle and quadrilateral's sides is $8$

Tags: geometry

My math teacher asked the question:

> The three sides of a triangle and the four sides of a quadrilateral can intersect each other at most $x$ points if this number is finite. What is $x$?

I wasn't sure at the beginning, but then after pondering a lot and looking at [this website](https://brainly.com/question/4799274#:%7E:text=A%20quadrilateral%20is%20a%20four,a%20rectangle%2C%20square%20or%20parallelogram.&text=Therefore%2C%20with%20this%20quadrilateral%20a,intersect%20with%20it%208%20times) on brainly.com (sorry Stack Exchange fans ) I came with the conclusion that $8$ was the maximum. However, I have got *no clue* how to solve this!!! Even after putting it to test on GeoGebra, I still haven't managed to make a firm proof on this topic.

Any help would be immensely appreciated ヾ(•ω•`)

[image: GeoGebra picture]
(the GeoGebra graph)

Comment: Here's an idea: each side of the quadrilateral must be straight. At most, how many times can a single straight line intersect the sides of a triangle? You have four sides to work with, does this help get you started?

Comment: Similar : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2708006

Comment: Yes @JeanMarie I have seen that thanks but it wasn't really too close to mine ;)

Comment: Thank you @JakeBrown this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is my final answer, thanks everyone for your advice :)

If there's anything wrong please let me know!

> [image: Page 1]
> [image: Page 2]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show  a line segment cannot intersect the interiors of all three edges of a triangle.